# 10 degrees rotation image cut off

Tags: iphone, image, uiimageview, rotation

I rotate my image with:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"doneBtn.png"];
CGImageRef imgRef = image.CGImage;

CGFloat width = CGImageGetWidth(imgRef);
CGFloat height = CGImageGetHeight(imgRef);

CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, degreesToRadians(10));

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextConcatCTM(context, transform);

CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0,0,width,height), imgRef);
UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

img.image=imageCopy;
```

When I display the image, I see it under my 10 degree but the image is cut off on the edges.

Does somebody know how to fix this? Here's an image for clarification.

[alt text http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/7077/problemkfr.png](http://img197.imageshack.us/img197/7077/problemkfr.png)

I have been trying all day yesterday, but can't figure it out.

Another example image:

[alt text http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/3370/afbeelding6b.png](http://img25.imageshack.us/img25/3370/afbeelding6b.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it now, i have to change the width/height value of bounds and
the x/y in CGContextDrawImage

```
CGRect bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, width+10, height+10);
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(10,0,width,height), imgRef);
```

Comment: I know this will solve the problem, but I think it is not a final solution, as you may have to change these values to bigger numbers as you increase the size of the image being transformed. Have you by any chance found the real solution for that? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

CODE IN SliderAppViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SliderAppViewController : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet UIImageView *imgView;
    IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISlider *mySlider;
- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(id)sender;  

@end
```

CODE IN SliderApp.m

```
#import "SliderAppViewController.h"

@implementation SliderAppViewController
@synthesize mySlider;

- (IBAction) sliderValueChanged:(UISlider *)sender {  

    imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(45);

} 
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    mySlider.minimumValue = 1.0;
    mySlider.maximumValue = 100.0;

        //other code
}
```

then make connection in IB

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is the anchor of your CALayer, I dont have example code right here with me,  but if you play with the anchor property of the view CALayer you should be able to get the view to look like you want. I will try and post some sample code later

Comment: do you have screenshots of the rotated view? i might be able to come up with what the anchor needs to be set at if i look at it

Comment: assuming that thats what the problem is :)

Comment: Its actually the same as my example image above, the degree and image size are  pretty much identical.

Comment: I added another image, i my edit. I hope this will clarify it a bit more, its just a "done" system button png. Its also mirrord right now but that will be of later conern, i first want it to rotate right.

Comment: Do you see whats going on then? The view is anchored at 0,0, you are rotation counter clock wise (right?)  so since the view is achored at 0,0 when you rotate the view is disappearing on the top there, try setting the anchor to .5,.5 and see what results you get, (wont be perfect but you might be able to figure it out) let me know if im on the right track

Comment: i found it, going to try it out now.

Comment: i had to import #import<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h> for using anchorpoint. I used this:

UIImage *image3=[self rotateImage];
imageView.layer.anchorPoint=CGPointMake(.5,.5);
imageView.image = image3;

but it didin't work.

Comment: the only thing that happens is that my UIImageview will get another x/y position when is set the anchorpoint.

Comment: When i use 
UIImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI*0.25)

My image is correctly displayed, but it get jagged edges on my image.

Comment: UIImageView.transform i mean imageView.transform

Comment: unfortunatly thats what happens when you do the rotation you get the jagged edges =/